# vbscript error path not found while using movefolder method

Tags: vbscript

I am fairly new to vbscript, and attempting to write a script that will pick up month and year stamped folders (2012_04) and move them to a year stamped folder (2012). I am getting a Path not found error though when I attempt to move the folder, and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere as to why it is happening.

```
for i = 0 to UBound(yearArray)
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(InputP)
    Set subFold = Folder.Subfolders
    yearStamp = yearArray(i)

    if not fso.FolderExists(ArchiveP & yearStamp) then
        fso.createFolder(ArchiveP & yearStamp)
    end if

    ArchiveP = ArchiveP & yearStamp & "\"

    for each dateFold in subFold
       Set fo = fso.GetFolder(InputP & dateFold.Name)
       folderName = InputP & dateFold.name & "\"
       foldName = fo.name & "\"

       if left(foldName,4) = yearStamp then
          fso.MoveFolder folderName , ArchiveP & foldName
       end if
    next

    ArchiveP = UnChangeP & PreArchP
Next
```

The error happens at fso.MoveFolder folderName , ArchiveP & foldName and I can't figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is caused by misconstructed paths. What you're trying to do is something like this:

```
fso.MoveFolder "C:\input\2013_03", "D:\archive\2013\2013_03"
```

However, what you're acutally doing is this:

```
fso.MoveFolder "C:\input\2013_03\", "D:\archive\2013\2013_03\"
                                ^                           ^
```

A trailing backslash is only valid in the destination path, and only if the destination path is the **parent** folder to which you want to move the source folder, i.e. your statement should look either like this:

```
fso.MoveFolder "C:\input\2013_03", "D:\archive\2013\"
```

or like this:

```
fso.MoveFolder "C:\input\2013_03", "D:\archive\2013\2013_03"
```

Avoid building paths via string concatenation. The `FileSystemObjects` provides a method [`BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) that will handle path separators correctly.

Your code is rather convoluted, BTW. Instead of using indexed access to `yearArray` you could simply iterate over all elements with a `For Each` loop. Also, your iteration over the subfolders of `InputP` already provides you with `Folder` objects. `fso.GetFolder(InputP & dateFold.Name)` is the exact same object as `dateFold`. Plus, `Folder` objects come with a [`Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxtftw67%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method, so you'd only need to handle the destination path.

I believe your code could be simplified to the following, which should do what you want:

```
For Each year In yearArray
  dst = fso.BuildPath(ArchiveP, year)
  If Not fso.FolderExists(dst) Then fso.CreateFolder dst

  For Each dateFold In fso.GetFolder(InputP).SubFolders
    If Left(dateFold.Name, 4) = year Then dateFold.Move dst & "\"
  Next
Next
```

In terms of performance it might be a good idea to switch the two loops, though. Iterating over folders means you have to read from disk whereas `yearArray` is in memory, thus the former iteration is bound to be slower than the latter. By making the subfolder iteration the outer loop (and putting the destination folder creation in a separate loop) you eliminate this bottleneck, because that way you read each subfolder just once.

```
For Each year In yearArray
  dst = fso.BuildPath(ArchiveP, year)
  If Not fso.FolderExists(dst) Then fso.CreateFolder dst
Next

For Each dateFold In fso.GetFolder(InputP).SubFolders
  For Each year In yearArray
    dst = fso.BuildPath(ArchiveP, year)
    If Left(dateFold.Name, 4) = year Then dateFold.Move dst & "\"
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for all the great info! This is the first thing in vbscript I have written, so it's nice to see what can or should be done with it!

Comment: So I am attempting to implement some of the code you have shown me, and I am getting an Invalid procedure call or argument on the 'dateFold.Move dst & "\"' line, and I can't find out what is going wrong with this line of code. One thing I didn't say was I am moving the folders withing the same drive, D:\input\2013_03 to D:\input\2013\2013_03

Comment: @user3076241 Your script tries to move the destination folder(s) into themselves, since they match your criteria (`Left(dateFold.Name, 4) = year`) as well. You need to exclude them from processing, e.g. by including the underscore in your check: `Left(dateFold.Name, 5) = year & "_"`.