# is there a way to move each file and folder of a drive in a folder in the drive itself using vbs

Tags: vbscript

I need a program in VBS (I can also use batch, but VBS would be better) that take all files and folders of my USB drive and move in a folder in the USB. example:
if in my USB drive there are these directories:

```
E:\folder1\file.txt
E:\folder2\foder3\file3.txt
E:\file.txt
```

after running the program there will be the following paths:

```
E:\newfolder\folder1\file.txt
E:\newfolder\folder2\foder3\file3.txt
E:\newfolder\file.txt
```

I don't know if that is possible. I've made a program using the for the cycle but it only works with files and not folders:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder("E:/")

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
fs.movefolder Subfolder.Path , "E:\newfolder\"
next
End Sub
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    .MoveFile "E:\*.*", "E:\newfolder\"
End With
```

*in this code the new folder already exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vbscript error path not found while using movefolder method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435041/vbscript-error-path-not-found-while-using-movefolder-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folder-object) object's [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/move-method-filesystemobject-object) method:

```
Dim sSourcePath
Dim sDestinationPath
Dim objFSO
Dim objSourceFolder
Dim objDestinationFolder
Dim objFolder

' Define paths
sSourcePath = "E:\"
sDestinationPath = "E:\newfolder\"

' Get source and destination folder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSourceFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sSourcePath)
Set objDestinationFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sDestinationPath)

For Each objFolder In objSourceFolder.Subfolders
    If objFolder Is objDestinationFolder Then
        ' Don't move destination folder
    Else
        ' Move folder to destination folder
        objFolder.Move sDestinationPath
    End If
Next
```

Comment: *"`MoveFolder` is not a method of the `FileSystemObject`."* Actually, [it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/movefolder-method).

Comment: This [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20442800/692942) explains the common problem with trailing backslash in the destination when using the `MoveFolder()` method. It also proposes using the method you have highlighted here more accurately and with more detail, which was over 7 years ago. Please do not leave answers to "obvious" duplicate questions, just flag it and move on.